# Loop to create multiple records in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, models

I am using Nokogiri to grab data from a webpage, so far i can save to one column in the model

```
def update_fixtures #rake task method
 Fixture.destroy_all
 get_fixtures.each {|match| Fixture.create(home_team: match )}
end

def get_fixtures # Get me all Home Teams
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
 home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map {|h| h.text.strip }
end
```

What I am wondering is the most efficient way to save to 2, 3 or 4 columms at the same time

So as an example I have another column called away_team and I would grad that data in the same way as the home team

```
away_team = doc.css(".team-away.teams").map {|a| a.text.strip }
```

is it advisable to put this within the get_fixtures method? and then add to the update_fixtures with something like

```
def update_fixtures #rake task method
 Fixture.destroy_all
 get_fixtures.each {|match| Fixture.create(home_team: match, away_team: match )}
end
```

After trying this the same data gets posted to the home and away columns.Which after reading back i can see why (I think its because match is only grabbing the home_team data?). How can i pass the attributes of the away team along with the home team?

This is all very new so any help provided is appreciated

Comment: why the same data gets posted for both? Inside get_fixtures method, `home_team` and `away_team` variables have different assignments so data should be different.

Comment: Im not sure, so am i going about this the right way? i get the same data posted for the home team and away team, so (H)Man Utd (A)Manutd.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the right approach because the variables `home_team` and `away_team` both are using the same common `match` and thus you are getting the same data for both.

Do the following:

UPDATE:

**Your model:**

```
 attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team

 def update_fixtures #rake task method
  Fixture.destroy_all
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))

  home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map {|h| h.text.strip }
  away_team = doc.css(".team-away.teams").map {|a| a.text.strip }

  Fixture.create(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team)
 end
```

Comment: yes makes sense, split it out and make each one a separate method, i guess i was trying to be too clever, keep it simple, thanks very much

Comment: hmm only the away team updating now

Comment: Any ideas as why it would only write to the one column

Comment: ok do create in one go as: `Fixture.create(home_team: home, away_team: away)}`. For that make a common method like `get_fixtures` with `home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map {|h| h.text.strip }` and `away_team = doc.css(".team-away.teams").map {|a| a.text.strip }.` But just don't use common `match` as you was doing previously for both.

Comment: nah that doesnt seem to be working either, how does it know what home and away is in the create command?

Comment: Then why don't you use `attr_accessor :home_team, :away_team`. Then just use- `Fixture.create(home_team: @home_team, away_team: @away_team)` in your `update_fixtures` method.

Comment: are we putting anything before fixture.create, are we still keeping the get_fixtures.each or is it get_fixtures(Fixture.create(home_team: @home_team etc))

Comment: Nothing like method.each. It is just a creation of fixture with two field entries: one for home_team and the other for away_team.

Comment: ok thanks, could i just ask the difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible ?

Comment: `attr_accessor` is giving you the getter and setter for undefined fields so that you can use them without being connected to db fields whereas `attr_accessible` gives you the ability to mass assign the protected attributes.

Comment: thank you, is that } supposed to be on the end of the create method?

Comment: i wasnt being funny, just clarifying. thanks but now i get cant assign to mass attributes

Comment: I knew that and so I told you about mass assignment. anyways I added that in code above. check attr_accessible above.

Comment: ok, i didn't think attr_accessor and attr_accessible were supposed to be used at the same time, attr_accessor is used for when i don't have a column in my model? so as i want to write to the model it should be attr_accessible. am i missing something here?

Comment: no, you can use both at the same time. The difference is correct but attr_accessor does more than that too. It provides getter and setter of their own to override with what rails auto do that so that you can change values inside. For your purpose it is just fine. Try it.

Comment: no doesnt like this either, undefined method get_home_fixtures

Comment: this error can't be judged until I see what's going on with the model in your app. That all code should be in model. But there is another way to do the same. I updated again to that way.